# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInf why?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making an application for android, the problem is that it is focused on android version 10+, and when I try to run it on version 5, it crashes at the first launch
what's wrong with that?

```
  --------- beginning of crash
    04-24 18:51:08.337 7048-7048/com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp, PID: 7048
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp/com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp.registerlogin.RegisterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
```

but why?

Comment: show full error log . do not truncate it

Comment: add build gradle file here too.

Comment: The issue is in your Register Activity xml file. Please share that here

Answer (score 0):

in your app go to buils.gradle and chaek if minSdkVersion up then 22 [image]

[image]